# How will the calendar reminders and/or tasks in SharePoint “pop-up” on a user’s screen?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, popup

i want to send an email notification or pop-up window on user screen, once i assigned a task to particular user in calendar list.

if i assigned a task to particular user giving start date and end date, at the time of start the process i want to send mail or pop-up and also at the time of due date i want to send mail or pop-up window message to that  task assigned user.[image]

workflow:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following can be accomplished with SharePoint Designer:

You can have a workflow that starts on item creation and then pauses until the Start Date. The next step of the workflow is sending the email notifying the assigned person the start date has been reached. You then have the workflow pause until the Due Date and then send an email to the assigned person letting them know the due date has been reached.

References:

[list of workflow actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164026%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Creating a workflow with Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: i am new to this SharePoint development. will you tell me the procedure.and i have followed this link. its not working:http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=64

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working from that link?

Comment: Mr.Todd,                                                    i have done the same procedure what was done on that link. but the workflow is not sending mail and its status is shown as Inprogress. and also it shows only same time when i trigger the task every time.

Comment: i have added the picture for your reference. please guide me what to do. and i want to know Is there any way of creating pop-up message to the user who assigned the task to him and have an reminder option.

Comment: saravanan, sorry for not responding sooner. I think the add 10 minutes variable method is not really needed in this case and may be adding unnecessary complexity. I would remove the first 2 actions in Step 1 and have your Pause action just Pause until the Due Date. If the workflow does not continue after the Pause action has met it's criteria, then there is probably an issue with the workflow engine on the server. I would try restarting the SharePoint Timer Service and/or checking on the timer job status in Central Admin to see if you can find an issue there.

Comment: On the popup question, I know of no way to have a popup occur using the SharePoint Designer workflow toolset.